# Align buttons(right) without moving the stack panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to Xaml. I want to build a custom title bar and set the DragMove() only to it. However, when I am trying to align the buttons to the right, the whole stack panel moves to the right, not just the buttons. I am not sure what should be done differently.

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel
            Height="40"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Background="red"
            MouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown"
            Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Button
                x:Name="btnMinimize"
                Width="40"
                Height="40"
                Background="Transparent"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                Click="btnMinimize_Click"
                Content="_"
                Foreground="White" />

            <Button
                x:Name="btnMaximize"
                Width="40"
                Height="40"
                Background="Transparent"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                Click="btnMaximize_Click"
                Content=""
                Foreground="White" />

            <Button
                x:Name="btnClose"
                Width="40"
                Height="40"
                Background="Transparent"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                Click="btnClose_Click"
                Content="X"
                Foreground="White" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

[Should be like this but the buttons on the right:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RcsQ.png)

[HorizontalAlignment="Right" makes it like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzBDl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used the FlowDirection to control the flow of the childrens but that make me change the order of the buttons; however it gives you the output that you are expecting.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel
        Height="40"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Background="red"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown"
        Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">


        <Button
            x:Name="btnClose"
            Width="40"
            Height="40"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            Click="btnClose_Click"
            Content="X"
            Foreground="White"/>


        <Button
            x:Name="btnMaximize"
            Width="40"
            Height="40"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            Click="btnMaximize_Click"
            Content=""
            Foreground="White" />



        <Button
            x:Name="btnMinimize"
            Width="40"
            Height="40"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            Click="btnMinimize_Click"
            Content="_"
            Foreground="White" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]